# asp.net MVC forms authentication with windows azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am a newbie with Windows Azure, and still learn it. I have developed an ASP.NET MVC project that implements Forms Authentication and is run on Windows Server.

Now, if I want to run this MVC project using Forms Authentication on Windows Azure, then I have some questions:

Question 1: Can MVC Forms Authenticaion function is possible with Windows Azure?

Question 2: If possible, then do I need to modify my existing codes? How can I do so?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to modify your code to run on Windows Azure. Just hook it up to a repository and create a new web site on Azure. Then connect the two and you'll have a fully functioning project.

Comment: thank you for your reply. May I know more details how can I "hook it up to a repository and create a new web site on Azure" as you told?  In other words, what are online resources or blogs that guide me to do those job?  Thank you in advance.